# Font size of text in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, font-size, text-size

I want to set the text size in my app. I have created different `layouts (layout, layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge)` and for `values (values, values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-nodpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi)`. But the problem is some devices in emulator have different sizes but having same dpi. So I am little confuse how to write different text sizes in `dimens` depending upon screen sizes not on dpi value. And how its work?

I think depending on device size android pick layout and then depending on dpi its choose values. Is it correct or not?

Edit-

I have one activity in my app to show text. I have scroll on text. And I set the values of text size in values-mdpi. But when I run my app on emulator `3.2"QVGA(ADP2)(320 x 480:mdpi)` scroll on text work. But when I run my app on emulator `5.1"WVGA(480 x 800:mdpi)` all text on half screen. I want size of text big on large screen although they belong `mdpi`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct. Depending on the device screen size and specification, android automatically loads the desired layout and all its elements and fonts.

Comment: if you got your answer, please accept this answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to create all layouts, just see this example it is working for me

```
Note :textviewtwo.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
      getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2014/01/adjust-text-size-in-all-android-devices.html

Comment: I do not want to do it programmaticaly in activity.